# I can't use slick slider properly, it's not showing any kind of result

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, slick.js

Here is my code, can anyone please help me find the error?

What I am trying to do here is to make a carousel where only 1 slide is shown and the other two are shown in the background. But the thing is that the code is not doing anything and just sitting there ideally.

I have already added all the updated files that are needed to run the slick slider program correctly.

Sorry for all the fuss, I am trying to get my head around this thing, and this is the first time I am using it in my project. Maybe I missed something, but I have already checked a hundred times.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/all.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/slick.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/slick-theme.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="slider slider-port row">
        <div>
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img
              src="./images/brickwork.jpg"
              class="card-img-top"
              alt="1. Bangalore Stone Works"
            />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Bangalore Stone Works</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img
              src="./images/concrete.jpg"
              class="card-img-top"
              alt="2. Porbandar Stone Works"
            />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Porbandar Stone Works</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img
              src="./images/brickwork.jpg"
              class="card-img-top"
              alt="3. Rajawadi Gate"
            />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Rajawadi Gate</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img
              src="./images/concrete.jpg"
              class="card-img-top"
              alt="4. Wooden Works"
            />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Wooden Works</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img
              src="./images/brickwork.jpg"
              class="card-img-top"
              alt="5. Compund Wall"
            />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Compound Wall</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img
              src="./images/concrete.jpg"
              class="card-img-top"
              alt="6. Flooring"
            />
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Flooring</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- TESTIMONIALS -->
    <section id="testimonial-section" class="p-4 bg-dark text-white">
      <div class="container">
        <h2 class="text-center">Testimonials</h2>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="test-slider text-center">
              <div>
                <blockquote class="blockquote">
                  <p class="mb-0">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Illo, sunt!
                  </p>
                  <footer class="blockquote-footer">
                    John Doe From <cite title="Company 1">Company 1</cite>
                  </footer>
                </blockquote>
              </div>
              <div>
                <blockquote class="blockquote">
                  <p class="mb-0">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Illo, sunt!
                  </p>
                  <footer class="blockquote-footer">
                    Steve Smith From <cite title="Company 2">Company 2</cite>
                  </footer>
                </blockquote>
              </div>
              <div>
                <blockquote class="blockquote">
                  <p class="mb-0">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Illo, sunt!
                  </p>
                  <footer class="blockquote-footer">
                    Megan Williams From <cite title="Company 3">Company 3</cite>
                  </footer>
                </blockquote>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <footer class="p-5">

    </footer>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/all.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/slick.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".dropdown").hover(
          function() {
            $(".dropdown-menu", this)
              .stop(true, true)
              .slideDown("fast");
            $(this).toggleClass("open");
          },
          function() {
            $(".dropdown-menu", this)
              .stop(true, true)
              .slideUp("fast");
            $(this).toggleClass("open");
          }
        );
      });
    </script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".test-slider").slick({
          dots: true,
          infinite: true,
          speed: 300,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          adaptiveHeight: true
        });
      });
    </script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".slider-port").slick({
          centerMode: true,
          centerPadding: "60px",
          slidesToShow: 3,
          responsive: [
            {
              breakpoint: 768,
              settings: {
                arrows: false,
                centerMode: true,
                centerPadding: "40px",
                slidesToShow: 3
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 480,
              settings: {
                arrows: false,
                centerMode: true,
                centerPadding: "40px",
                slidesToShow: 1
              }
            }
          ]
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your script tags need to be placed above the code you've written. Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: No errors are shown, just the code part I want to work is not working properly, and also after putting the script tags above does nothing.

Comment: Interesting. I'd then try and add those last three script tags (all.min.js/slick.js/main.js) above your js after the bootstrap.min.js script tag. Right now you are trying to use a plugin before the plugin code is fired.

Comment: still nothing, this is eating my brains!!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for putting you guys through this kind of torture, but after seeing the console what I found is that the filename was not written correctly and that is why it was showing an error - "Failed to load resource: net:: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND".

I checked all the file names and found that slick.js needed .min before .js in the name. After doing this, everything is working fine.

It's just that I did not see the console before and was getting frustrated watching that no solution is working properly.